# Disable scroll option in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Disable scroll option in EditText when the user enter more characters on that. Instead of scroll option i need to reduce the font/type size.

What i am currently doing is getting the count of characters and if it is exceeding a particular limit reducing the font size. What i want to do is when the scrolling option getting activated, need to reduce the size.

```
qQuestionEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            qCount.setText(String.valueOf(200 - s.length()));
            if (qQuestionEditText.length() > 180) {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(20);
            } else if (qQuestionEditText.length() > 150) {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(22);
            } else if (qQuestionEditText.length() > 120) {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(24);
            } else if (qQuestionEditText.length() > 90) {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(26);
            } else if (qQuestionEditText.length() > 60) {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(28);
            } else if (qQuestionEditText.length() > 30) {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(30);
            } else {
                qQuestionEditText.setTextSize(32);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try **setMovementMethod()** It will disable the EditText text scrolling. But you have to manage text size.

> editText.setMovementMethod(null);

Hope it will help you...

Comment: How to bring back the scrolling?
i tried `setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` to bring back scrolling but with this text selection not working to copy/cut

Answer (score -3):

use below properties for edittext-

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:lines="1"
android:maxLines="1"
```