# Disable Scrolling effect in EditText and still have visible cursor

Tags: java, android, jquery, xml, android-studio

I want to disable scrolling in EditText object. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23008904/6044778) but it resulted in disappearing of the cursor inside the EditText which is not intended. I want to disable the scrolling effect but still want the cursor inside the EditText. This is the XML of the EditText object.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@color/grayBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_view_carousel_grey_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/searchProducts"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to disable the scrolling in edit text box set static height for layout_height

```
<EditText

<!--set static height instead of giving wrap content-->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Comment: Yes it helped to achieve what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add in xml under `Edittext` tag:

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

or,

```
edittext.setCursorVisible(true).
```

Comment: Doing this was helpful the cursor disappears after entering even a single character.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @AbhayManiyar if the answer work ..you should mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign next to the answer...thankx